# SQL: Summing sales between date range defined in row or other table

Tags: sql, hadoop, cloudera, impala

I'm trying to query a my database (Cloudera Hadoop), and cannot wrap my head around what I need to do.  I'm trying me best to ask the question clearly, but I'm in over my head.  In case, I've added screenshots to help visualize the problem and the expected outcome.

If any additional information is needed, please comment.  I tried to simplify as much as I could, but maybe I missed something.

I have 3 tables.

***`Cal`*** Table has all the distinct weeks in 2018, in a YYYYWW format.
It also contains Month to date start and end weeks.
It also contains other date intervals (Quarter to date, Year to date, etc), but for simplicity I will exclude them from the question.

[image: Cal table]

***`POS`*** table contains my facts.

[image: POS Table]

***`Store`*** Table contains the store attributes.

[image]

I'm trying to obtain the following output:

[image: desired_output table]

I'm struggling to get the `MTD Sales` and other date ranges to populate.

```
SELECT
    pos.corp_year_week,
    pos.store,
    store.rep,
    sum(pos.sales) sales,
    ??????
FROM
    pos inner join cal on pos.corp_year_week = cal.corp_year_week
    inner join store on pos.store = store.store
GROUP BY 
    pos.corp_year_week,
    pos.store,
    store.rep
```

I'm contemplating the idea of doing a massive CASE statement for all my weeks and defining the between start and end dates for every `corp_year_week`, but I'm sure thats not the correct way to do it.

Any help would be **really** appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a sub-query to get the sum for the period given in `Cal`

```
SELECT p.corp_year_week, p.store, s.rep, p.sales, mtd.mtd_sales
FROM Pos p,
     (SELECT c.mtd_end, p2.store, SUM(p2.sales) mtd_sales
      FROM Pos p2, Cal c
      WHERE p2.corp_year_week between c.mtd_start and mtd_end
        AND p2.corp_year_week <= c.corp_year_week
      GROUP BY c.mtd_end, p2.store) AS mtd,
     Store s 
WHERE s.store = p.store
  AND mtd.mtd_end = p.corp_year_week
  AND mtd.store = p.store
ORDER BY p.store ASC, p.corp_year_week ASC
```

*This was tested on MariaDb (MySql) but it's pretty standard SQL*